# Is there a Java Console/Editor similar to the GroovyConsole?

Tags: java, editor

I'm giving a presentation to a Java User's Group on Groovy and I'm going to be doing some coding during the presentation to show some side-by-side Java/Groovy.  I really like the GroovyConsole as it's simple and I can resize the text easily.

I'm wondering if there is anything similar for Java?  I know I could just use Eclipse but I'd rather have a smaller app to use without having to customize a view.  What's the community got?

Screen shot of GroovyConsole:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/) is your best bet. It also has an [Eclipse plugin](http://www.drjava.org/eclipse.shtml) to use the interactions pane like GroovyConsole.

Answer (score 2):

try beanshell. its a scripting wrapper over java. http://www.beanshell.org/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the GroovyConsole ? Groovy accepts the vast majority of Java syntax

Comment: thanks for the tip.  Actually that is what I ended up doing.  My first thought was to keep the Groovy code and Java code in seperate editors, but by using the GroovyConsole I was able to show a POJO and and edit it in place to make it a POGO.

Answer (score 1):

One good reason for not using something like the Groovy Console (wonderful though it is) is when you want to test what something would be like in Java, without actually going to the trouble of a boilerplate class and main method to run snippets of code. There are some differences between what Groovy does and what Java does. It'd be nice to have a simple way to test something and know for sure it will work when you put it in Java.